# Same random image on push with a button

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make this code to generate a random number of 10 images, so every time I click the button I will get a random number of images and I just want this 1 image and the button doesn't disappear so I can try again.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input class="randombutton" type="button" value="Randomize" onclick="randomImg1()"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function randomImg1() {


      myImages1 = "Myimage.jpg";

      var rnd = Math.floor( Math.random() * 10 );

     document.write(myImages1[rnd]);
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to update the content dynamically, not using `document.write`. In addition, myImages1 must be an array.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input class="randombutton" type="button" value="Randomize" onclick="randomImg1()"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function randomImg1() {


      myImages1 = new Array();
      myImages1[0] = "Myimage.jpg";
      myImages1[1] = "Myimage1.jpg";

      var rnd = Math.floor( Math.random() * myImages1.length ); //incorporated other solution

      document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src='" + myImages1[rnd] + "' alt='image'></img>";
    }

</script>
<div id="image"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the * 10 of random should be the number of elements in the array.  the above could produce undefined as the image source.

Comment: @denov Added to solution

Comment: so you are saying that i need 10 image ?

Comment: @SørenPhithak Fixed it. A needed to be capitalized in Array();. And no, your array could have as many or as little images you want.

Comment: it is still not working i only get 1 image of the time i need it to get random numbers of images

Comment: It works for me in [Firefox](http://screencast.com/t/5TWowaqKm) and  [Chrome](http://screencast.com/t/SG1QLF9a5w). Check the Developer Consoles in these browsers.

Comment: nope this is not working for me i still only get 1 image at the time this is just not my night iam going to sleep now thanks for the help i will try again tomorrow

Answer (score 3):

myImages1 is a string an not an array.  And you need to multiple the random() by the number of elements in the array.

```
function randomImg1() {
   var myImages1 = ['Myimage.jpg'];
   var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * myImages1.length );
   document.write(myImages1[rnd]);
}
```